# How to create a rectangle of polylines using Autodesk FBX SDK

Tags: c++, polyline, fbx

How to create a rectangle of polylines using Autodesk FbxSdk ? I tried to create a rectangle using the AddPolygon method however i got two triangles forming a rectangle.